# JMeter and WCF with TCP endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, jmeter, load-testing

Does anyone know how to test a WCF TCP endpoint using JMeter?

I'm trying to set up a load test using the TCP Sampler, but when I add the net.tcp://myserver/myservice.svc to the Target Server input box I receive a 500 server error in response: java.net.UnknownHostException: net.tcp://myserver/myservice.svc

The TCP endpoint is working, I've tested it locally using visual studio, but having no luck with JMeter.

Does anyone have any replication steps or example links to help set up a WCF TCP test with JMeter.

I have found nothing on the internets to help with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A WCF TCP endpoint uses `NetTcpBinding`. Even if this binding uses many standards, it's intendended only for WCF-to-WCF communication. It's maybe one of the less interoperable WCF binding.

Please note that accessing the svc or wsdl is totally different from invoking the service.

Try to use another binding for your service (like `BasicHttpBinding`), or eventually try Visual Studio Load Testing.

Answer (score 1):

You may be making a mistake in server name, you must only put:

- myserver

Not net.tcp://myserver/myservice.svc